# Inject custom logic in Guice binding process

Tags: guice, guice-3

Is there a way to implement kind of before and after hook in Guice binding? E.g. before Guice calling a constructor to get the instance to be injected into a method, can I provide a logic check if the instance is already existed somewhere, if I can find the instance then I return it directly without calling the constructor; On the flip side is once an instance is constructed in Guice binding process, can I inject the logic to process that instance before it returned to the original caller?

Comment: You can probably use a `Provider` for this.  More advanced cases may need a `ProvisionListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom [Typelistener](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections) should do the trick. From what I understand your problem is similar to the "postConstruct" problem, executing code of an instance while guice is creating it. Maybe [this](https://www.holisticon.de/2012/08/postconstruct-mit-guice/) (german) blog article  wrote a while ago pushes you in the right direction.

1. Using a Matcher to define on which instances the listener should react.
2. using the afterInjection hook to work with the instance

   @Override
    public void configure(final Binder binder) {
       binder.bindListener(Matchers.any(), this);
    }

   @Override
    public  void hear(final TypeLiteral type, final TypeEncounter encounter) {
        encounter.register(new InjectionListener() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void afterInjection(final I injectee) {
           // alle postconstruct Methoden (nie null) ausführen.
           for (final Method postConstructMethod : filter(asList(injectee.getClass().getMethods()), MethodPredicate.VALID_POSTCONSTRUCT)) {
               try {
                   postConstructMethod.invoke(injectee);
               } catch (final Exception e) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(format("@PostConstruct %s", postConstructMethod), e);
               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   }

Comment: thanks for your response. PostConstruct is my second choice, what I really want is to hijack the construction process and replace the constructor calling with my own factory. Is it even doable?

Comment: I wouldn't know how.  Of course using providers gives you the freedom.